# How to trigger an event by a change to a listobject?

Tags: excel, vba

Excel 365.

When the user changes the value of a cell in a certain column of my Excel table (Listobject), I can use the `Worksheet_Change` event to trigger more code. I would use something like:

```
If Not Intersect(Target, Listobjects(1).listcolumns(2).DataBodyRange) Is Nothing Then
```

...to tell that one of these cells was changed. But how do I tell *which* cell it was?

On a releated note: Is there a way for `Worksheet_Change` to tell when a new row or column is added to the Listobject?

Comment: For example, by using `Msgbox Target.Address`.

Comment: If it's that simple then I'm embarrassed

Answer (score 0):

Sorry in advance if I misunderstood what you asked.

As `Target.Address` returns its cell location on the sheet, you can translate it to context of listobject by offsetting it with the location of first cell of the table

```
    With me.Listobjects(1)
        Debug.Print .DataBodyRange(Target.Row - .Range.Row  + 1, _
        Target.Column - .Range.column  + 1).Address(0,0)
    End with
```

secondly, if you can store the information of the initial table to some variables when opening the workbook, then you can compare the information every time workbook_change event takes place.

P/S: it is quite risky to leave a sheet that already has worksheet event macros in place like this to be unprotected and changed without restriction.

In a `Module`,

```
Dim start_LROW&, start_LCOL& 'Variable is declared first
Sub run_when_Open()
    With sheet1.ListObjects(1)
        start_LROW = .ListRows.Count
        start_LCOL = .ListColumns.Count
    End With
End Sub
```

in `Workbook_Open` event under ThisWorkbook module,

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
   Call Module1.run_when_OPEN
End Sub
```

in `Workbook_Change` event under Sheet module,

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    With Me.ListObjects(1)
        If Not Intersect(Target, .DataBodyRange) is Nothing Then
            If .ListRows.Count <> start_LROW Or _
            .ListColumns.Count <> start_LCOL Then
                Debug.Print "changed" 'Trigger some codes
                start_LROW = .ListRows.Count 'update the new information to be compared for next trigger.
                start_LCOL = .ListColumns.Count
            End If
        End If 
    End With
End Sub
```